# symfony - call a controller-action within a twig extention

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I'm trying to call a controller from a twig extention.
I do not want to call the [controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/master/controller/service.html) since I'd lose all the fancy shortcuts.

Want I want to achieve is to call the controller like twig do it when you do :

```
 {{ render(controller(
   'AppBundle:Article:recentArticles',
   { 'max': 3 }
 )) }}
```

I looked at the sourcecode of the "render" and tried to find the "controller" twig's functions, but I did not managed to understand how to do.
From now I achieved an unsatisfying but functionnal code :

In my twig extention :

```
return $environment->render('FooBundle:TwigExtension/CmsExtension:cmsRenderHook.html.twig', [
    'hook'  => $hook,
]);
```

In the `CmsExtension:cmsRenderHook.html.twig` template :

```
{{ render(controller(hook.stringControllerAction, hook.arrayParameters)) }}
```

I think (maybe wrongly) that it would be faster to call it without the template step.

**EDIT :** I finally successed to code this :

```
$environment->getExtension('Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\HttpKernelExtension')->renderFragment(
    $environment->getExtension('Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\HttpKernelExtension')->controller(
        $hook['action'],
        $hook['jsonParameters']
    )
);
```

(I did a grep in twig's cache and reproduced it compiled version).
my only concern is about referring to `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\HttpKernelExtension`, i'd rather let twig handle this choice, but I can't find out how.

**I have two questions:** 
- do you think that `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\HttpKernelExtension` is stable enought to refere explicitly to it?
- if not how would you do to let twig handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the `Twig_SimpleFunction` from the `Twig_Environment`:

```
$renderFunction = $environment->getFunction('render'); // get the env via initRuntime(..) in your extension
$callable = $renderFunction->getCallable();
```

However, I would not recommend relying on Twig internals. You should probably extract the functionality into a service.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I didn't manage to call the callable. Do I have to use a call_user_function or to use it as an anonymous function? (I used PHP 5.2 for years so I ask howfully stupid questions, sorry)